# Native Device Orientation issue in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, orientation, landscape, portrait

I'm working with Flutter and I'm using [Native Device Orientation Plugin](https://github.com/rmtmckenzie/flutter_native_device_orientation)

I'm trying to know the device orientation and manage my view based on that.

That plugin works really well, but I found an issue when I'm in page `A` which has a `NativeDeviceOrientationReader` and go to page `B` which has another `NativeDeviceOrientationReader`.

In this case, the page which is supposed to has a `NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft` will have `NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight` even if I didn't change the orientation in the middle.

> Note: If I rotate the phone after changing the page, it begins to work properly.
>   Also if I delete one of the `NativeDeviceOrientationReader's` it works ok too.

*I'm using this code:*

```dart
NativeDeviceOrientationReader(
    builder: (context) {
    NativeDeviceOrientation orientation = NativeDeviceOrientationReader.orientation(context);
    var quarterTurns = 0;
    if (orientation == NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft) {
          quarterTurns = 3;
     } else if (orientation == NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight) {
          quarterTurns = 1;
     }
  }
),

(...)
```

I don't know if somehow I have to close the reader or something.

Thanks in advance !

## -------------- EDIT 1 --------------

Actually I didn't fix the issue, but I could resolve my problem changing one `NativeOrientationReader` to flutter `OrientationBuilder`, because I realized I didn't need the current rotation, I only wanted to know if the phone is landscape or portrait.

Thank you.